# Why does Task<TResult> wait for result before awaiting it?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library

I'm trying to understand TPL. Unfortunately I can't get over Tasks with return types. From what I've read, I thought that assigning a task to a variable starts it asynchronously. When you need the return value, you just await it, which ensures that the current thread waits for the `Task<T>` to complete.

Example on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/library/hh524395.aspx):

```
// Call and await in separate statements.
Task<int> integerTask = TaskOfT_MethodAsync();

// You can do other work that does not rely on integerTask before awaiting.
textBox1.Text += String.Format("Application can continue working while the Task<T> runs. . . . \r\n");

int result2 = await integerTask;
```

My understanding: the first statement should start the task, immediately after that the text box is appended. Then the thread is blocked until `integerTask` is completed.

However, when I was trying it on my own, it didn't work that way:

```
static void Main()
{
    var task = new Task(RunItAsync);
    task.Start();
    task.Wait();
}
static async void RunItAsync()
{
    // Should start the task, but should not block
    var task = GetIntAsync();
    Console.WriteLine("I'm writing something while the task is running...");
    // Should wait for the running task to complete and then output the result
    Console.WriteLine(await task);
}
static Random r = new Random();
static async Task<int> GetIntAsync()
{
    return await Task.FromResult(GetIntSync());
}
public static int GetIntSync()
{
    // Some long operation to hold the task running
    var count = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) count++;
    }
    return r.Next(count);
}
```

There is no output, after a few seconds it outputs everything at once:

```
I'm writing something while the task is running...
143831542
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think you need to take a step back and more thoroughly understand all the concepts needed to make asynchrony work. Stephen Cleary's series of articles are a good introduction to the subject matter. http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html

Comment: Yes, sadly I was wrong about most of the things I have learnt.

Comment: It's tricky stuff. If you want a more technical, though somewhat out-of-date introduction to this stuff, I wrote a series of articles when we were designing it. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/tag/async/.  Start at the bottom, these are listed from most to least recent.

Comment: Thanks for all your help, I will look into it

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> rom what I've read, I thought that assigning a task to a variable starts it asynchronously.

That is completely wrong.

Here, I've got a task: make a sandwich.  I write that down on a piece of paper and I put it in a drawer marked "tasks".  Did I start making a sandwich? No.

I start making a sandwich. Did starting to make a sandwich cause a piece of paper with a description of the task to appear in my drawer? No.

Variables and tasks have absolutely nothing to do with each other. Whatever caused you to believe that they had something to do with each other, stop believing that now.

> When you need the return value, you just await it

Yes.

> which ensures that the current thread waits for the task to complete.

No, if by "waits" you mean "blocks".

> My understanding: the first statement should start the task

Sure, assuming that TaskOfTMethodAsync starts the task and returns the started task, which seems reasonable.

> immediately after that the text box is appended

Yes.

> Then the thread is blocked until integerTask is completed.

ABSOLUTELY NOT.  The whole point of the await is to NOT block the thread! If you give me a task -- make a sandwich -- and you await me completing that task, you don't go have a nap while I'm making you a sandwich! You keep getting work done! Otherwise what is the point of hiring me to make you a sandwich?  You want to hire workers to do work for you *while you do something else*, not while you sleep waiting for them to finish.

> What am I doing wrong?

Two things. First, you're making a void method into a task, which is very wrong. The asynchronous method should not be void, it should return a task! A task represents asynchronous work. Second, you're only returning completed tasks!

Let's go through this line by line and say what it does.

```
var task = new Task(RunItAsync);
```

Create a task to represent the action.

```
task.Start();
```

Start the task on the thread pool.

The main thread then blocks on the completion of the task.

All right, this method is running on the thread pool:

```
static async void RunItAsync() 
{
```

What does this call do?

```
    var task = GetIntAsync();
```

Well, let's look:

```
static async Task<int> GetIntAsync()
{
   return await Task.FromResult(GetIntSync());
}
```

First thing it does is call GetIntSync. That runs for a long time.  Then it returns a value. Then we produce a **completed** task that represents that value. Then we await that task. Awaiting a completed task produces the value.  So this is exactly the same as

```
   value1 = GetIntSync()
   task1 = completed task representing value1
   value2 = value of task1
   task2 = completed task representing value2       
   return task2
```

There is nothing asynchronous here at all. This is a very, very complicated way to write "return GetIntSync()" -- you run the method, and then you construct not one but TWO completed tasks representing the task already completed!

Again: this method returns a task. All the sub-tasks of this method have completed already, so we simply return a completed task with the value.

What happens to that task?  Remember we were at:

```
var task = GetIntAsync();
```

So that task is completed. (This is the "task2".)

```
Console.WriteLine("I'm writing something while the task is running...");
```

No, you're writing something after the task has completed. You returned a completed task!

```
// Should wait for the running task to complete and then output the result
Console.WriteLine(await task);
```

No, the task has already completed. This extracts the value without awaiting and prints it. There's nothing to await; the task is already done!

Now what is returned from this method?  Nothing.  Its a void method.  So we now return, having done all the work of the method.

What happens next?  The delegate passed to the original task has finished running on the worker thread, so the task running on the worker thread completes and signals the main thread that it can stop waiting.

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of problems.

1. You're not starting anything asynchronous here. async-await doesn't automagically makes things asynchronous or creates any threads. Read [stephen's introductory article on the subject](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html)

   To offload some work, you need to use`Task.Run` or `Task.Factory.StartNew`.
2. You're using `async void` method; there is no easy way to wait for its completion. You should be using `async Task` instead. [Read more](http://www.jaylee.org/post/2012/07/08/c-sharp-async-tips-and-tricks-part-2-async-void.aspx)

So your code becomes:

```
static Task<int> GetIntAsync()
{
    return Task.Run(()=> GetIntSync());
}

static async Task RunItAsync()
{
    // Should start the task, but should not block
    var task = GetIntAsync();
    Console.WriteLine("I'm writing something while the task is running...");
    // Should wait for the running task to complete and then output the result
    Console.WriteLine(await task);
}
```

Also you don't need to start the tasks manually using `task.Start();`; `Task.Run` already hands you a started task.

Given that two changes your code should work as expected

Answer (score 1):

There are two big problems I see here:
the FIRST is your use of [Task.FromResult(result)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194922(v=vs.110).aspx): it's nothing more than wrapping result so it looks like a Task, so you can use Task's methods on it. When you call `return await Task.FromResult(GetIntSync());`, it:

1. computes `GetIntSync` completely,
2. returns an `int`,
3. passes it to `FromResult`,
4. instantly return with a finished `Task<int>`,
5. call `await` on a finished Task, so it continues right away,
6. and returns the `Task<int>`.

GetIntAsync isn't asynchronous at all! The SECOND big problem is you are mixing testing your asynch/await skills(which also use `Task`), with parallel execution using `Task.Run`. Asynchronous execution means that the execution order of the thread isn't necessarily synchronous to the code order. You execute the code in the asynchronous method as soon as you can. An async method can await, giving control back to its caller, until it signifies it is ready to work again. The purpose of this is to keep the thread, and thus CPU, busy. To illustrate, let's use my favorite mechanism: metaphores!

- Let a logical processor be a desk worker. Every time slice, you walk to a desk(thread) with a folder(method) on it, processing the forms inside it(lines) one after another. If a line is a method, you grab that folder, process the forms inside, then go back to the folder you were working on.
- Then one form X requires a signature from your boss. You give it to your boss: the asynchronous method `Task task = GetBossToSign(Form X)` was called from `Worker.WorkDay()`. You then work on the other forms. When you get X back with a signature, you finish up X, and then continue where you were, not wasting a second.
- But now you come to a form Y that requires X to have been completed. Luckily, `Worker.WorkDay()` was marked as `async`, so you can call `await task` to signify: work on the folder beneath this one, until you see X returned to you, still working on this process. Only folders that are marked `async` can be safely put away by `await`.
- On the other hand, if you called `task.Wait()`, you're marking this desk as off limits(blocking the thread) until task has finished. This also happens if you use `await` while already working on the bottom folder. The worker(processor) will try to find another desk with work on it(readied thread), that may not be related to the actual process you're trying to streamline.
- If you are calling `Task.Run(RunItAsync)`(Or creating a task and then starting it), you are going to some empty desk, and leave a folder RunItAsync there. You are going to work on your own desk. Optimally, the work can be done twice as fast. If you're the only worker(processor), this does nothing, as you're just going to spread your shifts(time slices) working at both desks.
- So now what your code does: A Thread works at desk A, where folder Main is. It grabs the folder `RunItAsync`, puts it on empty desk B, and then marks this desk as unusable. A worker at desk B(which may or may not be the same worker) calls `GetIntAsync`, and then `GetIntSync`. He fills in the forms himself, puts the finished folder on desk C with `Task.FromResult`, then checks if the folder is on desk C is finished with `await`. It is! So the `await` does nothing, `GetIntAsync` returns. The finished `Task` is assigned to task, B prints the first line, checks and sees that `task` is already finished, and prints the second line. The folder `RunItAsync` is done, so desk A is marked usable, and desk B is abandoned. A worker(which again may or may not be the same worker) goes to desk A and executes whatever comes after `task.Wait()`.

  - So nowhere in your program do two workers work at the same time, nor are any executions executed asynchronously with the written code.

To test your asynch/await skills, just use an asynch method already available, e.g. `WebClientDownloadStringTaskAsync("http://stackoverflow.com")`. Example:

```
//Calling asynch method, running on the same thread,
//doing the work as it is eligible for doing.;
Task<string> x = new WebClient().DownloadStringTaskAsync("http://stackoverflow.com");
Console.WriteLine("I'm writing something while the task is running...");
Console.WriteLine("Content of webpage is: {0}", await x);
```

This executing thread passes on control to the caller of the current method, until the downloading is done, by using `await x`.

To test your Task parallelization skills, any synchronous work will do.

```
//Calling Task to delegate work to be done in parallel,
//running(hopefully) on another thread.
Task<int> longTask = Task.Run(() => {Thread.Sleep(1000); //this is hard work
                                     return 1;});
Console.WriteLine("I'm writing something while the task is running...");
Console.WriteLine("The number one is: {0}", await longTask);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have

```
public static int GetIntSync()
```

Getintsync is there just a normal boring routine, you called it before writing the first line, so its doing all the work, then saying, im doing something else.

The example works because the function called is an async function, so its set up with

```
Task<T> something = myAsyncFunc(params)
Now output im going to do something
T result = await myAsyncFunc..
```

Now result has the result do other things.

Its like setting up a deligate

The first line is basically a deligate, so doesnt action your code. Your codes on hitting do me, at the await line.

See [microsofts example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx)

My ipads so not the best place, but hopefully can see your error and how to fix it